# Emacs Won't Load My ~/.config/emacs/init.el... Unless I Do This

Tags: init-file

I'm new to Emacs so I ended up following along with a tutorial by System Crafters. In the video he notes that he is not loading his primary configuration for the tutorial, so he loads an Emacs template with this command `emacs -q -l init.el` straight from the folder he created.

I setup all my settings in the `init.el` file, but now, they only load if I open Emacs while in the `~/.config/emacs` directory (I am using Kubuntu Linux). The `init.el` file also only loads if I run Emacs the same way as in the template: `emacs -q -l init.el`. This is really annoying if I want to open Emacs from any directory. It works, but it's a workaround that I'd like to avoid if possible.

This is what's in my `init.el` file:

```
;; Emacs Configurations

(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ; don't show splash screen at startup
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen, .fullboth)) ; full screen at startup

(scroll-bar-mode -1) ; disable scrollbar

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.config/emacs/themes") ; add theme path
(load-theme 'dracula t) ; load dracula theme


;; Org-Mode Configurations

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/org-mode/lisp") ; load org-mode

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'org-store-link) ; org store key bind
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda) ; org agenda key bind
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'org-capture) ; org capture key bind

(setq org-adapt-indentation t
      org-hide-leading-stars t
      org-odd-levels-only t) ; set adapt indentation w/ clean stars

(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Org/test.org")) ; add test.org to agenda view
```

I tried going to my `~/Org` directory and run Emacs using `emacs` and `emacs -q -l init.el` and both gave the same error stating the No such file or directory 'init.el'.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, obviously if you specify just the filename `init.el` then Emacs can only look in the current directory for the file. If you want it to load the file from a specific directory, *simply specify the specific directory*. It’s as easy as `emacs -q -l ~/.config/emacs/init.el`.

Comment: Okay this definitely works. I may have to make a bash alias for that though because it a bit tedious to type out every time. Thank you!

Comment: The real question is why are you bothering to specify any path at all? Especially when `~/.config/emacs` is one of the default locations that Emacs looks when you _don’t_ use the `-l` option…

Answer (score 0):

See the Emacs manual, node [Action Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html).

That tells you how to use command-line option `-l` to load a library:

```
-l FILE’
--load=FILE
```

> Load a Lisp library named FILE with the function `load`.  If `FILE`
> is not an absolute file name, Emacs first looks for it in the
> current directory, then in the **directories listed in `load-path`**
> (*note Lisp Libraries::).
>
> *Warning:* If previous command-line arguments have visited files,
> the current directory is the directory of the last file visited.

So if you don't want to specify the absolute file name for your `init.el` file, you can just add the directory where you put it to the value of variable `load-path`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "/directory/where/you/store/your/init-file/")
```

Comment: I tried adding the load-path as the directory, but it would still only open the exact same way. Is it possible there is conflict with my org-mode load-path?

Comment: Sorry; I don't know what you mean. You have only one `load-path`. It's a list of directories. If you have a separate question please post that separately.